# byte[] when parsing Base64 string to image NULL

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, base64

I am getting a base64 string from web service call. I am then trying to take that string and place it into an image view within a listview. I am getting a null point exception on the line byte[]. I am not sure what I am doing wrong or why I am getting null there when I debug I am able to get the array and step through.

```
String peepPicData = peepWithPic.getThumbnailData();
                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(peepPicData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT); //the null is here
                Bitmap parsedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
                holder.mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);
```

I am not sure why it's null when it converts to an array and steps through. I have tried this Base64 string in a converter on a browser and it works.

I am getting the Base64 string with peepWithPic.getThumbnailData(); but then get null in bytep[].

If I take that base64 string and plug it into String peepPicData = "theactualBase64string" I get the picture over and over. Why would this not work with just getting it from the getter since its already being set before this call?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a null check because some of the peepWithPic do not acutally have pics. Here is the updated code

```
if (peepWithPic.getThumbnailData() != null) {
                String peepPicData = peepWithPic.getThumbnailData();
                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(peepPicData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap parsedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
                holder.mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);
            }
```